# Show displayName in Angular 8 from Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, observable, angular8

I am having a problem displaying the "displayName" property from my component.ts file (for testing purposes in console.log), yet it works fine from the template.

**component.ts:**

```
 constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private auth: AuthService
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
    console.log(this.auth.user.displayName); // this line is the problem
  }
```

But yet, this works fine in the template:

**component.html**

```
{{ user.displayName }}
```

And in case you need more details of the service...

**auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
  ) {
    //// Get auth data, then get firestore user document || null
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to subscribe to the observable.

```
this.auth.user.subscribe(user => {
  this.userForm.get('email').setValue(user.email);
  this.userForm.get('displayName').setValue(user.displayName);
});
```